i cant interact tty when `docker compose up`
Dockerfile
CMD [ "bash" ]

compose.yml
stdin_open: true
tty: true

When I run docker compose up the bash prompt does not come up, neither input nor output works. it stays that way

Attaching to kvirc-1

but when I run up -d and attach or run run it comes up.
and what exactly is compose start useful for?
I understand that stopping a container and then starting it can restart CMD. but I get this error
$ sudo docker compose up --no-start
[+] Creating 1/0
 ✔ Container client-kvirc-1  Created                                                                                    0.0s 
$ sudo docker compose start --dry-run kvirc
service "kvirc" has no container to start


docker-compose start isn't usually useful.  If you wind up with a container that's created-but-stopped, deleting the container and re-running docker-compose up -d will get you into a known-working state.
